# I want to change content using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, html-select

**Select Course**

```
<select>
    <option value="b.a">B.A</option>
    <option value="b.com">B.Com</option>
    <option value="b.b.a">B.B.A</option>
</select>
```

**Select Semester**

```
<option value="1">1st</option>
<option value="2">2nd</option>
<option value="3">3rd</option>
```

Now what i want is that when i select first course i.e. `b.a`. then no. of semesters shud be only one displayed in "Select Semester" list and for b.com these shud be 2 and forr b.b.a these shud be 3,i.e. once the course is selected page shud automatically refresh and the number of semesters shud change accor to the subject chosen,regarding this how can i accomplish this using js or jquery or ajax,kindly help me by providing some example or tutorial.

Comment: You dont need to refresh page, you need to learn to use ajax. Make selection one ajax your server for what to put in select 2 and so forth and so on

Comment: @SpYk3HH can  tell me abt sum examples

Comment: http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example using jQuery and AJAX

> HTML

```
<select id="selPrimary">
    <option value="b.a">B.A</option>
    <option value="b.com">B.Com</option>
    <option value="b.b.a">B.B.A</option>
</select>
<select id="selSecondary"></select>
```

> Script

```
// jQuery doc.ready function
$(function() { // all "action" script goes in here
    // Selects primary "select tag" by ID and assigns change event
    $("#selPrimary").on("change", function(e) {
        // Empty the options that might exist 
        // (from last choice in primary) and prep 
        // secondary for new options
        $("#selSecondary").empty();
        // .post is jQuery short hand for .ajax(..."type=post"
        $.post("someFolder/someController.php", // this first param tells location of your php backend controller
            function(data) { // this is the function that acts if the post is "successful"
                $("#selSecondary").html(data); //  fills secondary select tag with our new options
            },
            "json"); // this last param tells how to return the data
    });
})
```

> Controller (PHP in this case)

```
$retValue = "";
//Get Post Variables. 
if (isset($_POST['selPrimary'])){
    $value = $_POST['selPrimary'];   
    switch($value) {
        case "b.a":
            $retValue = '<option value='1'>1st</option><option value='2'>2nd</option<option value='3'>3rd</option>';
            break;
        case "whatev":
            $retValue = '<option value='1'>1st</option><option value='2'>2nd</option<option value='3'>3rd</option>';
            break;
    }
}

echo json_encode($retValue);
```

Comment: of course, you can run other server side functions for building the option HTML however you want

Answer (score 0):

You could try this...

```
<script>
function changeSem(sub)
{
 if(sub == 'b.a')
 {
  document.getElementById('sem').innerHTML = "<select id='semnum'>
<option value='1'>1st</option>
</select>";
 }
 if(sub == 'b.com')
 {
    document.getElementById('sem').innerHTML = "<select id='semnum'>
<option value='1'>1st</option>
<option value='2'>2nd</option>
</select>";
 }
 if(sub == 'b.b.a')
 {
    document.getElementById('sem').innerHTML = "<select id='semnum'>
<option value='1'>1st</option>
<option value='2'>2nd</option>
<option value='3'>3rd</option>
</select>";
 }
}
</script>
Select Course
<select id="sub" onchange="changeSem(this.value);">
<option value="b.a">B.A</option>
<option value="b.com">B.Com</option>
<option value="b.b.a">B.B.A</option>
</select> 
Select Semester
<div id="sem"></div>
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Why do so many ppl claim jQuery and then use javascript pure ... `document.getElementById('sem')` should be `$("#sem")`

Comment: OP didn't EXPLICITLY say jQuery. In fact, the title reads "JavaScript OR jQuery" (emphasis mine).